# cannot make a wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

Does anyone know why i cannot make text around this wrapfigure ? 
i have tries to move the image but with no success to make the text around the image [image]

here the latex code:

```
\documentclass[apaper,12pt,spanish, preprint,times]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Verano 2015}}
\date{} 
\maketitle
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\centering{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip} Despues de mucha espera y planificación el verano pasado pude conocer una
tierra que siempre he deseado conocer, un pais que siempre me llamo la atención, que me brindó conocer
playas paradisiacas, pueblos mágicos, y una dulce gastronomia, con estas linias voy a compartir con ustedes
mi experiencia de viaje a México hace un año.
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{\newline Palabras Clave: }} #1}
\keywords{Vacaciones, verano, México}
\end{abstract}
{\centering{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}}
\newpage
\flushleft
\section{Introducción}
México es un país situado en América latina, cuenta con una población de $112\,322\,757$ de habitantes y su lengua oficial es el español.
El territorio mexiano está conformado por 32 estados y un distrito federal, uno de sus mayores atracciones turísticas es el caribe
y más concretamente Cancún a la cual se puede ir por vuelos con coste asequible desde Madrid.
Es por ello que desde hace varios años se ha convertido en un destino vacacional muy frecuentado por los españoles. Un ejemplo de ello es mi amigo Carlos que hace unos años viajó en verano a Cancún y quedó tan alucinado por el viaje que se convertía en el tema de convesarción cada vez que nos veíamos, creo que de tanto escucharlo hablar tan emocionado de su viaje de verano por México, causó un interés y deseos en mí por conocer ese país, sin dareme cuenta comencé a buscar en internert información sobre México y me emepezó a interesar cada día más, veía fotos de sus playas, de algunas de sus ciudades, de su gastronomía y de la cultura maya.
\newpage
\section{Playas paradisíacas}
\subsection{Cancún}
Mi primer destino de llegada fue Cancún, el cual me recibió con una calurosa bienvenida, inmediatamente me trasladé a mi hotel y aunque estaba cansado por el viaje, no pude esperar para cambiarme, ponerme el bañador y explorar la playa. Realmente la playa es espectacular, es de textura fina, clara como la leche y que decir del mar truquesa que inspira tranqilidad, el agua es templada y muy tranquila. Realmente Cancún es un lugar que enamora con sus playas, hoteles de lujo donde te olvidas un rato de la crisis ya que por un bajo costo tienes todo incluído, es decir hospedaje, alimentos y bebidas hasta saciarte. 
\begin{minipage}[hbp]{8in}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{cancun.jpg}
\end{minipage} \\
Y que decir de su vida nocturna lleno de restauarntes pintorescos, donde puedes encontrate hasta con el mariachi y bailar la cucaracha, para después trasladarte a una diversidad de bares coquetos con música alegre y en mi caso ya no pude continuar la fiesta por que andaba cansado del viaje, pero cuentan que las discotecas son muy animadas.
\subsection{Playa del carmen}
Mi segundo destino fue playa del carmen el cual se encuentra a unos 40 minutos en autobús desde Cancún, al llegar ahí se nota un ambiente más europeo con su quinta avenida llena de tiendas de grandes marcas, restaurantes con terraza, algunos bares coquetos y con un ambiente y paisaje más rustico. La playa es linda, la arena es menos clara que la de Cancún pero siempre es blanca y fina. El mar tiene oleaje y es de un color más verde. Y en cuanto a la vida nocturna destaca el ir de bar en bar de copas a bares frente a la playa con musica lounge y un ambiente más relajado. Un plus de playa del Carmen es que desde ahí se puede tomar el tour a isla mujeres y la excursión a Xel Ha.
\section{Gastronomía}


\end{document}
```

Comment: without knowing what document class and other packages you're using, this will be hard to answer.  please expand your example so that it's compilable, and we can cut-and-paste the code to experiment.  (that's a most attractive beach.)

Comment: Might have something to do with your `minipage` being 8 inches wide and your image that you are tying to fit inside the `minipage` being 10 inches wide.  Also, where are you trying to use `wrapfigure`?

Comment: What is `[hbp]` supposed to do in the optional argument for the `minipage`? And what about the class options `apaper`, `preprint` and `times`? By the way, `\centering` doesn't take an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First (like said) use the package wrapfig
then

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.6\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{cancun}
\caption{beautiful beach}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate `\usepackage{wrapfig}` into your preamble.